# Are ImageJ Maven dependencies in maven central?

Tags: maven, dependencies, imagej

I am planning to use ImageJ for a webapp but it seems ImageJ maven dependencies are not in the central maven repository.

- Am I right?
- Is this going to change when ImageJ 2.x is released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the ImageJ maven dependencies at [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gov.nih.imagej/imagej).

Listed versions are `1.40 - 1.46`.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to use the 1.46 dependency. Any idea when the 2.x version will be released to the repository listed above?

Comment: You're welcome. I have no idea when 2.x versions will be accessible. Sorry :-(

Comment: Never mind. I'll keep an eye on the progress of the dev team and use the 1.46 in the meantime. :-)

Comment: Note that the `gov.nih.imagej:imagej` artifacts were done by a third party. The official releases can be obtained from maven.imagej.net. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 7):

*EDIT: Updated on July 4, 2014 to reflect the latest status.*

The builds on Maven Central with groupId `gov.nih.imagej` were done by a third party, but the official ImageJ 1.x builds *are* available from Maven Central with groupId `net.imagej` and artifactId `ij` starting from version `1.48r`; e.g.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
  <artifactId>ij</artifactId>
  <version>1.48r</version>
</dependency>
```

[Older official builds of ImageJ 1.x](http://maven.imagej.net/content/groups/public/net/imagej/ij/) are available from the [ImageJ Maven repository](http://maven.imagej.net/). It also has [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) builds which consist of several artifacts all prefixed by `imagej-`. You can use it via the following configuration:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>imagej.public</id>
    <url>http://maven.imagej.net/content/groups/public</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

It is suggested to model your POM after the [ImageJ Tutorials](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-tutorials). These projects inherit from the [ImageJ parent POM](https://github.com/imagej/pom-imagej), which avoids repeated boilerplate configuration sections.

We plan to begin submitting builds of ImageJ2 to Maven Central soon.

For more information about using Maven with ImageJ, see:
    http://imagej.net/Maven

Answer (score 1):

You might be searching for this snippet?

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>  
    <artifactId>ij</artifactId>  
    <version>[1.45s,)</version>  
</dependency>
```

Found it [here](http://imagej.1557.n6.nabble.com/ImageJ-2-0-0-alpha5-maven-repo-td3682689.html). There might be other useful maven snippets for you as well.